# Hiding a column in a table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I found an example that was previously suggested to use for someone else that fit their necessary need,([Demo link to the suggested fix](http://jsfiddle.net/highwayoflife/8BahZ/4/)) I tried to simplify the process by making each column hide able by using the col tag. yet when I added the class to the col tag, it broke the feature and I'm not sure how to fix it.

My Demo: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8BahZ/393/)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, then you just need to add class to those `th`'s like below,

```
<tr>
 <th class="first_name">First Name</th>
 <th class="last_name">Last Name</th>
 <th class="email">Email</th>
</tr>
```

And modify your script a little like below,

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = $("." + $(this).attr("name"));
    $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var column = $("." + $(this).attr("name"));
    $(column).toggle();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8BahZ/400/

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be toggling the `col` tags and not the columns themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For me, in Chrome, a `col` tag expands to other tags (`thead`, `th`), so selecting `col` will not get you anything. Even if you would get them, you're toggling merely the column headers.

Anyway, you have a syntax error as the console tells you - you cannot have `;` in an expression as it terminates a statement.

A cleaner solution may be using `:nth-child`: http://jsfiddle.net/8BahZ/402/.

```
var f = function() {
    var index = $(":checkbox").index(this) + 1;
    $("table > * > * > :nth-child(" + index + ")").toggle(this.checked);
};

$(":checkbox").click(f).each(f);  // bind handler and run it once
```